# Calculating a complex integral with generalized Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, line-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

> Calculate the integral $$\oint\limits_{|z|=2}  \frac{z^m}{(1-z)^n}\mathrm{d}z, \, \text{for}\ n,m\in \mathbb{N}$$

So in fact of the denominator I think I have to use the generalized Cauchy integral formula. I got this:
$$\oint\limits_{|z|=2} \frac{z^m}{(1-z)^n}\mathrm{d}z = \frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}f^{(1)}(n-1)=\frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\cdot m (n-1)^{m-1}$$

Is this the answer? That seems to easy, but the pole is inside the circle and $z^m$ is a holomorphic differentiable function. So I think there is no problem, isn't it? Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get the idea of an evaluation at $n-1$? Did you switch the derivative order with the evaluation point?

Comment: The GCIF is given by $f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial D_r(z_0)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}dz$. So I thought one can take the first derivation and $n-1$. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And now compare with how you actually applied that formula. You should probably translate first to
$$
\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(z_0)=\int_{|z|=2}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}dz
$$

Comment: Do you mean the binomial theorem in your solution?

Comment: Using the binomial theorem is just an alternative to get the Laurent expansion and the coefficient for $\frac1{z-1}$. Your calculation has serious arithmetic and transcription errors.

Comment: Ah okay, I see, thank you. So the solution is right, only the transcription ist wrong?

Comment: The idea is correct, the presented execution terrible and the result wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you will get the result if you apply the Cauchy formula correctly,
$$
\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{f(z)}{(z-1)^n}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(1).
$$

---

Alternatively, you can apply the binomial theorem to
$$
z^m=(1+(z-1))^m
$$
to find
$$
\frac{z^m}{(z-1)^n}=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k(z-1)^{k-n}
$$
where the only term giving a non-trivial integral is with $k-n=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$'th derivative of $z^m$, $m\ge n$ is given by

$$\frac{d^n z^m}{dz^n}=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}z^{m-n}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{z^m}{(1-z)^n}\,dz&=2\pi i \frac{(-1)^n \,m!}{(n-1)!(m-n+1)!}\\\\
&=2\pi i (-1)^n\,\binom{m}{n-1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! Why did you get $(-1)^n$?

Comment: @jacmeird : It is the difference between $(z-1)^n$ and $(1-z)^n$.

Comment: @LutzL Ah, yeah, thank you! I swapped the notation, sorry. But I can't see the $f^{(n-1)}$ derivative in this solution?

Comment: @jacmeird : In applying the derivative formula, the $n$ was replaced by $(n-1)$. But incompletely, it should be $(m-n+1)!$ in the denominator. The final result is again correct.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for catching the typo.  Much appreciative.